# SSIS - Can't Read XML - The file is being used by another process

Tags: xml, ssis, oledb, etl

I am not able to read an `XML` file using `SSIS`. My goal is to read it and then insert the data into a `MSSQL` database (it would be a lookup table)

This is my data flow so far

[image: Data Flow]

where the process "Leer Usuarios" (Read Users in english) is the one which is in charge of reading the xml.
An example of the xml file is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<NewsItemsTable>
    <NewsItemRow>
        <ID>1</ID>
        <Edad>28</Edad>
        <Estado_Civil>Soltero</Estado_Civil>
        <Sexo>F</Sexo>
        <Provincia>Ciudad Autonoma Buenos Aires</Provincia>
        <Localidad>La Paternal</Localidad>
    </NewsItemRow>
    <NewsItemRow>
        <ID>2</ID>
        <Edad>28</Edad>
        <Estado_Civil>Soltero</Estado_Civil>
        <Sexo>F</Sexo>
        <Provincia>Ciudad Autonoma Buenos Aires</Provincia>
        <Localidad>La Boca</Localidad>
    </NewsItemRow>
</NewsItemsTable>
```

and the XSD (generated by SSIS) is

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="NewsItemsTable">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="NewsItemRow">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="ID" type="xs:integer" />
              <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="Edad" type="xs:short" />
              <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="Estado_Civil" type="xs:string" />
              <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="Sexo" type="xs:string" />
              <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="Provincia" type="xs:string" />
              <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="Localidad" type="xs:string" />
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

When I run this dataflow, I get the error on the XML Source that the xml file is being used in another process. I don't have any other program using it, I have even restarted the machine (MS Server 2003) and I still have the same issue.

[image: XML Source task failed]

and the error message in progress tab

[image]

The translation for the error would be

> The process could not access the file  because it is being used
>   by another process

What could be causing this problem ? How can I fix it ?
I am pretty new to SSIS, so if you need more info I can provide it.

Thanks in Advance

**UPDATE**
What I've noticed (because I've a backup of the xml) is when I read the XML for the first time with the ETL it inserts a lot of dummy data as forms of nulls.

Those nulls weren't there before

[image: Extra Nulls]

What could be causing this issue ? Might this be related with the original problem ?

Comment: Try renaming the XML file in windows explorer to double check that it is in use. Then download process explorer (http://serverfault.com/questions/1966/how-do-you-find-what-process-is-holding-a-file-open-in-windows) and work out what has the file open. Is that your entire package?

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid yes I am able to rename the XML file. I have other packages but none of the other tasks is reading any xml.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the issue

The logging was enabled and the log entries were written into the same file I was trying to read. I misunderstood the configuration of logging, and I had put the wrong file. Now I picked a new xml fresh and it is working correctly.

Comment: Thanks for returning and posting your solution!